# exercise about method classes

Tags: java, class, methods

i have a strange problem about the recalling of the class distanza. The terminal say that it can't find the symbol of method distance and i don't know the reason. I'm a newbie programmer of java. Please help me if is possible.
The problem is the following:
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/WX2LE.png][1]

Class Distributore and Class Posizione:

```
Class Distributore:`public class Distributore{
     private Posizione pos; //ATTRIBUTI
     private double disp;
}


public Distributore(Posizione pos,double disp){ //COTRUTTORI
    this.pos=pos;
    this.disp=disp;
}

public Posizione getPosizione(){        //METODI
    return pos;
}

public double getDisponibilità(){
    return disp;
}

public static double calcolaDistanza(Distributore start, Distributore end){
    return distanza(start.getPosizione(),end.getPosizione());
}


}`

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Posizione {

private double x,y; //ATTRIBURI

public Posizione( double x,double y){ //COSTRUTTORI
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
}

public  double getX(){      //METODI
    return x;
}

public  double getY(){      //METODI
    return y;
}

public  String toString(){  //METODI
    return "("+x +","+y +")";
}

public static double distanza(Posizione p1,Posizione p2){
    double d = Math.sqrt(((p2.getX())-(p1.getX()))*((p2.getX())-(p1.getX()))+(((p2.getY())-(p1.getY()))*((p2.getY())-(p1.getY()))));
return d;
}


}
```

Comment: `distanza` is a method of the `Posizione` class, so to call it from another class use `Posizione.distanza`.

Comment: you probably want `Posizione.distanza(...)`

Comment: thank you so much , you solve m problem!!